# NPM run dev successful in vscode but not terminal (contenlayer + Nextjs)

Tags: npm, next.js, terminal

I am a bit at a loss on this one. Everything in my terminal (hyper) was working just fine the other day until I closed out of it. I came in to launch a Nextjs app I had been working on and now npm run dev just hangs up and doesn't actually start. The strange thing (to me) is that Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal seems to run just fine (and much quicker).

So far, the only packages I have added are contentlayer and next-contentlayer besides the default nextjs packages. Basically, contentlayer looks for md files (in a difined dir) and then generates an api for them. Strangely this seems to work everywhere else but in my actual standalone terminal.

Hyper.js:
[image: Hyper terminal]

Visual Studio code integrated terminal:
[image: Visual Studio Code integrated terminal]

I have found that if I remove makeSource from the contentlayer.config.ts file, next dev will still run. At this point I could just use vscode, but I would really like to figure out the issue on all of this.